# Retrieving value of lookup entity using CRM REST BUILDER

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am new to CRM Dynamics . I have a requirement.

Lets assume that I have 2 related Entities : `"Cat"` and `"Dog"` and I have simple fields `"Cat_Food"` and  `"Dog_Food"` on them respectively . I have a lookup field of Entity Dog on Entity Cat's Form named as `"Lookup_Cat"`. Now as soon as a lookup value of Dog is selected , I want Cat's `"Cat_Food"` field to be populated with the (selected lookup)Dog's `"Dog_Food"` field's value using Javascript.

Now I have seen on many websites that CRM REST BUILDER was suggested. I had Used it but It is not populating and neither giving any error: Here's the code:

```
// JavaScript source code

function abc(executionContext)
{
var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
var new_dogfood;
var lookup = new Array();
lookup = formContext.getAttribute("Cat_Food").getValue();
if (lookup != null)
{
var name = lookup[0].name;
var id = lookup[0].id;
var entityType = lookup[0].entityType;
}
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/Dog(id)?$select=Dog_Food", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (this.readyState === 4) 
    {
    req.onreadystatechange = null;
    if (this.status === 200) {
    var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
    new_dogfood = result["Dog_Food"];
    }  
    else 
    {
    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
    }
}
};
req.send();
var x =  formContext.getAttribute("Cat_Food");
x.setValue(new_dogfood);
}
```

Comment: Did you debug to see what’s going on?

Comment: Yes. It is not going inside  if(this.status ==200 )

Comment: so what “else” part says in alert?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Webpi for retreiving data and especially Lookup Id, Lookup primary name and Lookup Entity schema name, you have to include annotations in your request header.

```
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
```

I will post a short example of request here for Account and I am trying to get Primary Account (lookup) on Account entity and Primary contact (lookup) on Account.

request as below

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/accounts(290FB459-D1F4-E911-A813-000D3A4AA4FD)?$select=name,_parentaccountid_value,_primarycontactid_value", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
            var name = result["name"];
            var _parentaccountid_value = result["_parentaccountid_value"];
            var _parentaccountid_value_formatted = result["_parentaccountid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
            var _parentaccountid_value_lookuplogicalname = result["_parentaccountid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"];
            var _primarycontactid_value = result["_primarycontactid_value"];
            var _primarycontactid_value_formatted = result["_primarycontactid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
            var _primarycontactid_value_lookuplogicalname = result["_primarycontactid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"];
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
```

and here is the response I get

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://abc.xyz.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/$metadata#accounts(name,_parentaccountid_value,_primarycontactid_value)/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"23463189\"",
    "name": "ABC Account name",
    "_parentaccountid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Account Reassignment - 3010 NE",
    "_parentaccountid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.associatednavigationproperty": "parentaccountid",
    "_parentaccountid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname": "account",
    "_parentaccountid_value": "75e562f9-06fb-e911-a813-000d3a4aa2c1",
    "_primarycontactid_value": null,
    "accountid": "290fb459-d1f4-e911-a813-000d3a4aa4fd"
}
```

Now for you what intresting is from above code is below 4 lines of result for parent account

```
"_parentaccountid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Account Reassignment - 3010 NE",
        "_parentaccountid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.associatednavigationproperty": "parentaccountid",
        "_parentaccountid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname": "account",
        "_parentaccountid_value": "75e562f9-06fb-e911-a813-000d3a4aa2c1",
```